# SetInterval and clearInterval in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

This was asked upon searching here, but the solutions were not working, or I have missed something.
This is the snippet of the code

```
tick(rev_new_arr) {
    if(rev_new_arr.length > 0){
        this.setState({
            sim_play_date : rev_new_arr[0]
        },()=>{
            rev_new_arr.shift()
        })
    }else{
        this.stopPlay()
    }
  }
playMap(){
        const startDate = this.state.simulation_date;
        const sim_dates = this.state.sim_dates;
        const index_simdate = parseInt(sim_dates.indexOf(startDate) + 1, 0);
        const new_arr = sim_dates.slice(0,index_simdate);
        const rev_new_arr = new_arr.reverse();
        this.timerID  = setInterval(()=> this.tick(rev_new_arr), 1000);     
}

stopPlay(){
    console.log(this.timerID);
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
}
```

`setInterval` works but when adding the function `stopPlay()` on click event in a button, it does not stop and still calls the `tick` function.

**EDIT:** I tried logging the timerID in console..It outputs 2 ids. I think that is the reason, why it's not stopping even calling `clearInterval`. What must be the reason of this?

Comment: can you create a sample working fiddle with this code? because it should work.

Comment: Is it possible you are calling playMap() more than once before calling stopPlay()?

Comment: No, `playMap` is called on click event assigned to button, same as `stopPlay`

Answer (score 0):

Are your methods `playMap()` `stopPlay()` and `tick()` bound to the class? If not, try defining them like:

```
stopPlay = () => {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it is all bound, I tried logging the `timerID` in console..It outputs 2 ids. I think that is the reason, why it's not stopping even calling `clearInterval`.

Comment: Without seeing more code, I suspect that you have this component included twice somehow. What you have there should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` is referring to global context,so bind it.

```
stopPlay(){
    console.log(this.timerID);
    clearInterval(this.timerID).bind(this);
}
```